# Which step ring do I need?

Tags: lens, filters, filter-diameter

I've bought two step up/down rings for my Sony lens and both are incorrect.

I have two Sony lenses, both with 55mm filter ends. I've just bought my self a Poloroid Slide Duplicator lens which is 52mm but has a 52mm to 58mm ring included.

Firstly I bought a 58mm to 55mm step down ring, but when I received it, it wouldn't fit. I assumed that I bought it the wrong way around and should've bought a 55mm to 58mm step up instead.
Then I accidentally bought a 52mm to 58mm step up as I clicked on 52mm instead of 55mm.

I just need to check that I need a 55mm to 58mm (if I use the 58mm ring included in with the duplicator) or a 55mm to 52mm step down to go directly from the 55mm lens to the 52mm duplicator??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two choices:

1. You can use a *Step-Down* ring in the flavor of 55mm to 52mm. You'll attach the ring to your lens and then connect the rig to the Duplicator. You can ignore the ring that came with the Duplicator.
2. The ring that came with the Duplicator attaches to the 52mm side of the Duplicator and then exposes a 58mm side for attachment to a lens. In this case, you would need a 55mm to 58mm *Step-Up* Ring.

Either one of these options will get your lenses attached to the Duplicator. Personally, I'd go with Option 2 and get Step-Up rings, as you may find some additional use with them with attaching filters in the future. I very rarely end up using Step-Down Rings, as they're likely to cause vignetting.

Comment: if the duplicator is going from 52mm to 58mm and then you go to 55mm on the lens, will this not have the same effect as stepping down from 55mm to 52mm? ...surely the result will be the same in terms of vignetting either way?

Comment: @dazzathedrummer - in your case, yes the vignette will be the same. My comment re: vignetting is more in regards to general use of step down rings, especially when the end goal is to apply a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your lens has a 55mm filter thread. You want to attach an accessory that has a 52mm thread. You need a 55-52 step-down ring.